# Why drupal include my code into comment in my TPL

Tags: theming

Why drupal include my code into comment in my TPL.

in tpl in my module. Drupal include my php code into comments.

```
<!--?if($form["#Xcoords"]):?-->
<!--?$x=(json_decode($form["#Xcoords"], true));?-->
<!--?endif;?-->
```

So I didn't understand it(((

Comment: The proper tags are <?php ...... ?> not html comment tags.

Comment: If you can improve the question (and refrain from using abusive language to members of the community in comments), do so and flag it to see if it can be re-opened. See the [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) if you don't understand what that means

Answer (score 2):

They are HTML comments, not PHP ones. And HTML comments are outputted. Proper way to comment out your code would be:

```
<?php /* if($form["#Xcoords"]): */ ?>
<?php /* $x=(json_decode($form["#Xcoords"], true)); */ ?>
<?php /* endif; */ ?>
```

Comment: I asked not about how to comment. I Asked about why in my tpl. After activate my module. Drupal change my tpl. And include my PHP CODE INTO HTML COMMENT TAG!

Comment: @Postman you didn't even mentioned your module in your question. Please edit your question and provide details - especially description what your module is doing with template files (with relevant source code).

Comment: @Postman Drupal doesn't change your template, either your server config or custom/contrib code are responsible

Comment: I found problem. Drupal didn't understand standart Pro coding sintacis. So every time, I must write <?php, and evrytime must check if(!empty()). But it stupid, everywhere in php we can just write <? and if(!$some). And drupal didn't understand this <?if(somthing):?>html<?endif;?>

Comment: It's not Drupal, it's your server. And don't forget [using short tags is discouraged by PHP official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)